# How to remove the tab-like space after an empty line?

Tags: spacing, text

I want to write sth like:

aaaaaaaaaa

[empty line]

bbbbbbbbb

but instead I often get this:

aaaaaaaaaaaa

[empty line]

__bbbbbbbbbb

When I try skips inbetween, they do not start where they should, but rather in the middle of the text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried `\noindent` after the empty line and immediately ahead of `bbbbbbbbb`?

Comment: If you want to never have such an indent,  you can have `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` in you preamble (before `\begin{document}`)

Comment: thx a lot, worked perfectly

Comment: However in this case, load the `parskip` package, to increase the vertical spacing between paragraphs. Note that paragraph  indent is good typographic practice.